# Converting Java Compiler to Linux

Tags: java, linux, compiler-construction, javac

Basically, I have a compiler for some of my Java scripts, it works just fine on Windows - but I've tried endlessly to make it work on Linux - yet no luck.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javac.exe" -d bin -cp lib/*; -sourcepath src src/com/ar/*.java src/com/ar/cache/*.java src/com/ar/cache/loaders/*.java src/com/ar/cores/*.java src/com/ar/function/*.java src/com/ar/function/item/*.java
pause
```

That works just perfectly.

Basically what i did, was that I changed the pathing of the Javac (worked perfectly), as well.
Tried removing the space & putting a semicolon.

Thanks.

Comment: What jdk do you have installed on your linux box?  What is the failure message?

Comment: JDK1.7.0_40.
With the following code: **/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac -d bin -cp lib/; -sourcepath src src/com/ar/.java src/com/ar/cache/.java src/com/ar/cache/loaders/.java src/com/ar/cores/.java src/com/ar/function/.java src/com/ar/function/item/*.java** It gives out: 
**compile.sh: line 1: -sourcepath: command not found**

Then I removed the -sourcepath & it just gives out bunch of errors complaining about the actual Java code (which is not faulty by the way). Seems like it's trying to process the Java code as a parameter or something.

Comment: As a start, get rid of the semi-colon after the "-cp lib/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you new to Linux?  Linux doesn't execute batch scripts like Windows, instead it executes shell scripts.  Shell scripts are far easier to work with and far more powerful, but the syntax is different and therefore a Windows .bat file won't just magically work in Linux.

An equivalent script might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -d bin -cp lib/ -sourcepath src $(find src -name '*.java')
```

A few tips: Paths in Linux are denoted with : whereas paths in Windows are denoted with ;

The $(find...) invocation is basically just a shortcut to say "all the .java files in src".

Otherwise, listing them all out manually as you have done in your original example works just fine too.